# How do I voxelize and fill a 3D textured OBB?

Tags: graphics, collision-detection, linear-interpolation, voxel, rasterizing

I have a set of Minecraft blocks and for each of them I want a volume (of an arbitrary size) containing the voxelized Minecraft block.

A Minecraft block isn't just an AABB that fills the whole block. It generally is a set of children AABBs that can be translated/scaled/rotated (OBBs) and can have a different color/texture for every face. Here's an example:

[image]

I have already developed a class called `ModelVoxelizer` that takes in a 3D triangular model and gives out the voxelization of it and to do that uses the OpenGL graphics pipeline. The issue with it is that it sets on the volume just the contouring voxels of the model. Instead, I want the Minecraft block voxelization to be filled inside.

[image]

A slice of the volume I'd (*hopefully*) get with my current `ModelVoxelizer` by voxelizing the 3 OBB (not always I have AABB!) that compose the Minecraft block above.

[image]

A slice of the volume I want (basically the one above but filled). The voxels inside should have a color averaged from the faces of the texture.

**The problem:**

So my problem is a rasterization problem where I have the volume (the 3D grid) and a OBB (a part of a Minecraft block) and I have to check which voxels are inside the OBB. For those that are inside/colliding I have to interpolate the values of the faces of the OBB (texture/color), based on the distance of the voxel from said faces.

Is it an already known issue? Am I trying to re-invent the wheel?

I appreciate any kind of suggestion about this, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just do exactly what you said: find the voxels inside the OBB, and interpolate the values of the faces based on distance. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you specify the actual prolem (i. e. where you are getting stuck) more concretely? You already specified the necessary steps to solve your problem, which can be implemented [quite](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/428676-fastest-point-within-obb-test/) [easily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation).

Comment: @EvilTak I'm glad to hear something like that can work. This was exactly my question, I wasn't sure if my path was right and if there was something better. Sorry if I've been unclear.

Comment: @Tau mine wasn't actually an issue, I had an idea on how to solve it but I wasn't sure if there was any better, smartest, way to 3d interpolate those voxels. The link is really useful thank you!